# Cross Domain Session

Tags: javascript, java, authentication, grails, extjs

The projects of the company I work for are being changed, the names are App A, App B, App C and App D. One of this changes is the login and session.

Two applications (A and B) has the same database, this means user has one login/pass for both. Often these applications are used in parallel.

I have an API for login, which returns a jwt, but one active token is allowed at a time.

Then I was asked to make the login flow work for Apps A and B, using the same JWT to maintain a single session.

One problem I encountered is that the projects were not necessarily in the same domain.

The questions are:

1. What is the correct way to make this work? Following good security practices.
2. Where can the token be stored? To be accessible by both applications (is this possible?).

---

The actual flow:

- The user enters credentials into the form.
- Request to the backend API.
- Request to the login API.
- Response with read-only session information (daysToExpirePass, ttl, name, login, tokenCreatedDate, email and token).
- Only the token (signing) is sent in each request to the backend API to check permissions, the other information is just for other things like warnings, all the logic is in the backend.
- This information is stored in session storage.

---

Technologies:

- ExtJS 7.6.0 - frontend
- Grails 5.2.2 and Java 11 - backend
- Internal Logic for Authentication.

---

JWT payload structure example:

```json
{
  "sub": "<user>",
  "RANDOM_VALUE": "<uuid>",
  "jti": "<uuid>"
}
```

Comment: You've got to set SameSite:None on your session cookie. I did this in PHP

Answer (score 0):

To implement a shared session and JWT authentication across multiple applications (App A and App B) using different domains, you need to consider the following aspects:

Single Sign-On (SSO): Implement a Single Sign-On solution that allows users to log in once and access multiple applications without having to re-enter their credentials. This typically involves using a centralized authentication server.

Cross-Domain Authentication: As the applications are on different domains, you need to address Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) issues. Ensure that the authentication server and the applications are configured to handle CORS properly.

Here's a high-level approach to achieve this:

Authentication Server:

Create a separate authentication server (or use an existing one) that handles user authentication and JWT token issuance.
Configure this server to issue JWT tokens with a shared secret and a common signing key.
Login Flow:

User logs in to App A or App B.
The frontend of App A or App B sends a request to the authentication server to authenticate the user and obtain a JWT token.
The authentication server verifies the user's credentials, creates a JWT token, and returns it to the frontend of App A or App B.
Store the JWT token in a secure HTTP-only cookie or use a secure storage mechanism like local storage.
Cross-Domain Authentication:

Ensure that the CORS settings on the authentication server allow requests from the domains of App A and App B.
You might need to implement mechanisms like JSONP or Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) to facilitate communication between different domains.
Token Sharing:

The JWT token can be shared between App A and App B as long as they have the same signing key. This means they can validate the token independently without making additional requests to the authentication server.
Whenever App A or App B needs to perform an action on behalf of the user, they can check the JWT token for permissions and authentication. This is a stateless way to verify the user's identity.
Single Logout:

Implement a Single Logout mechanism if you want to log the user out of both applications when they log out of one. This typically involves notifying the authentication server to invalidate the user's session.
JWT Payload:

Your JWT payload should contain user-specific information along with claims necessary for authentication and authorization.
Be cautious about the claims stored in the JWT, as they will be readable on the client side.
Security Considerations:

Ensure that you follow security best practices, such as using secure cookies, implementing proper token validation, and securing the JWT signing key.
Regularly rotate the JWT signing keys for enhanced security.
Logging and Monitoring:

Implement comprehensive logging and monitoring to keep track of authentication and authorization events and detect any suspicious activities.
User Experience:

Make sure the user experience is smooth, with appropriate error handling for login and session management.
Keep in mind that implementing a shared session and authentication across different domains can be complex and requires a robust understanding of authentication and security practices. Additionally, it's essential to consider regulatory and compliance requirements, such as GDPR, when handling user data across multiple applications.